# Prediction of time series using AR(1) on the difference of the time series in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, predictive-models, arima

I have a time series (quarterly data) that I will use to predict the upcoming 4 quarters.The total number of observations is 20 quarters, thus, I need to predict quarter 21 -> 24.
First I took the diff(data) to have a stationary data and I want to fit AR(1). I am using the following in R:

`arima(diff(data), order=c(1,0,0))` and I obtained: ar1 (- 0.2441) and Intercept (1.2004)

Is the following correct?

```
∆y(t+1) = 1.2004 - 0.2441*∆y(t)

∆y(t+2) = 1.2004 - 0.2441*∆y(t+1)
```

If I want to predict y(t+1), do I find ∆y(t+1) and then

```
y(t+1) = y(t) + ∆y(t+1)

y(t+2) = y(t) + ∆y(t+1)+ ∆y(t+2)
```

and so on... until y(t+4)

Is this analogy correct? Do you know how can I get the predicted value in R without doing it manually? How can I tell R that first I need to predict the delta and then the original value.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Gennaro Tedesco gives the forecasts for the differenced data. If you need forecasts for the original data, you may use

```
predict( arima(data,order=c(1,1,0)), n.ahead=4 )
```

where the `order` argument being `c(1,1,0)` rather than `c(1,0,0)` reflects that you want to fit an AR(1) model to *differenced* rather than original data. In other words, specifying the middle number in the `order` argument to be `1` rather than `0` does the differencing for you.

Regarding why you cannot obtain the same results manually as obtained by `arima`, perhaps the problem is the following. "Intercept" in the output of an ARIMA model in R may be a little misleading. That is, an AR(1) with "intercept" equal to $\mu$ means (in R)

$$ (x_t-\mu) = \varphi (x_{t-1}-\mu) + \varepsilon_t $$

rather than

$$ x_t = \mu + \varphi x_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t. $$

The latter part of my answer is based on [this](http://www.stat.pitt.edu/stoffer/tsa2/Rissues.htm) post, see especially **ISSUE 1**. Meanwhile, **ISSUE 2** is very relevant to the former part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply. The command

```
forecast(model, h=4)
```

will predict ∆y(t+i), is there a way to predict y(t+i) directly in R?
I used the command

```
predict (model, n.ahead=4)
```

and I had the same values as forecast. However, if I do it manually and use the coefficient of the autoregression, the values of ∆y(t+i) are different than teh one provided by the forecast or predict commands. Do you have an idea why?

Thank you!